# Efficient regex to insert missing apostrophes?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression and replacement string that I can use to insert missing apostrophes. Examples:

> Dont -> Don't
>
> Ill -> I'll

I can get this working with capture groups, but I'm trying to only have to call .Replace one time. Right now I have something like:

```
$apostropheregex = '\b((didn|won|ain|don)(t)|(i)(ll|m))\b'
$apostrophereplacement='$2$4''$3$5'
```

But it feels ugly to be mashing together both prefix groups and both postfix groups with the assumption that we only matched one or the other (either a "ll" or a "t" match)

Does anyone have any suggestions? Is there a better way to approach this problem? Should I indeed treat these as two separate scenarios and run replace twice with separate regexes and replacement strings?

Update: To clarify, I'm aware that this could have unintended consequences, replacing strings that shouldn't be replaced since English grammatical context is not considered. I'm running this manually after reviewing strings first and I still think this is an interesting question.

Comment: What regex flavor?

Comment: @Laurel appears to be php

Comment: "Stupid Dont, wouldn't understand that English is not trivially-parseable, must have been ill. So I shot it. Now I'll need a a new Dont that don't only do trivial parsing."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a note: This is ill suited for... *ill suited*, which becomes *i'll suited*.

But you asked for a better regex and you shall receive. I would use:

```
\b(?|(don)(t)|(won)(t)|(you)(re))\b
```

The replacement will be `$1'$2`.

The main advantage of this regex is legibility. You should easily be able to add new alterations.

It works by using the branch reset group `(?|  )`. This means that each alternation uses `$1` and `$2` (instead of 2n+1 and 2n+2).

Comment: Thanks. I realize that this opens up the possibility of some overcorrection, but the context in which I'm using this is such that the risk is pretty low. The regex you suggested is certainly much more readable. Thanks!

Comment: Also, thanks for enlightening me about branch reset groups. Very cool.